# Changing RouteData in Asp.Net Core 3.1 in Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I've recently updated my .Net Core 2.1 application to 3.1 and there is one part that has not upgraded as expected.

I'd written code to map subdomains to areas as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512403/area-and-subdomain-routing/60706663#60706663)

I now realise that the method of using `app.UseMvc()` should be replaced with `app.UseEndpoints()` but I can't find anywhere in the 3.1 framework that will allow me to write to the `RouteData` before `app.UseEndpoints()`

```
//update RouteData before this
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "admin", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Is there a way to write to `RouteData` using Middleware?

I've tried going back to `app.UseMvc()` as it's still in the framework but `MvcRouteHandler` doesn't seem to exist anymore

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.DefaultHandler = new MvcRouteHandler(); //The type of namespace could not be found
    routes.MapRoute(
        "admin",
        "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Add a reference to using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` and use `Httpcontext.GetRouteData()` method to achieve `RouteData`

```
app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

    string url = context.Request.Headers["HOST"];
    var splittedUrl = url.Split('.');

    if (splittedUrl != null && (splittedUrl.Length > 0 && splittedUrl[0] == "admin"))
    {
        context.GetRouteData().Values.Add("area", "Admin");
    }

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
    await next();
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "admin", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! I was attempting to use middleware but I thought GetRouteData() was only a getter and didn't realise you could do .Values.Add() to it.

Comment: Note that sequence matters ! This "app.Use" must come AFTER "app.UseRouting", but before "app.UseEndpoints". Also, new in .NET Core 5: You can also put it into context.Items["host"] = "foobar"; That's not RouteData, though.